# Pulling a sub-set of an SQL Server Dataset using comboboxes

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, ado.net

I am trying to "convert" a more complex Access database/user interface into a custom app using VB .NET.  I am also a NOOB in .NET so please be gentle.

Here are the steps I'm trying to take to duplicate my results in .NET
1) Create a Data Source (dsServer) to my SQL Server that pulls all tables and all data. I created this Data Source in my project already using the UI.

2) Create a Data Table (dtResults) in my Data Source that pulls all the info I need from 3 tables:
[Person] - This is a single entry list.
[Primary Teacher] - This is linked through column (Primary) on the [Person] table. This will return single results. 
[Test] - This is liked by [Person].ID. This table has multiple entries per [Person]
I have also created this data table in my project under the data source using the UI.

3) Populate 12 comboboxes on a form that will be used to "filter" my results onto a DataGridView.  Each combobox needs to be a DISTINCT list of what is in dtResults. Each time a combobox changes, the results in the DataGridView need to be updated as well as all the other comboboxes. (narrowing the choices to only what is available)

4) Create a DataGridView on the same form that will display the filtered results.

I don't seem to have any issues with creating the datasource or the datatable.  What I can't figure out is how to populate the comboboxes from the datatable or how to bring back my filtered results to the datagridview.

Any help on the best way to accomplish this would be great.

Comment: ". I am able to pull datasets from the SQL Server no problem. What I can't figure out is how to properly filter the results into a sub-set". how about a SQL WHERE clause in the original query? Or you can set a Filter on a DataTable object in the same kind of way

Comment: Agreed, however I don't know how to properly build a WHERE clause that would have 12 variables in it.  What I also don't know is if it is better to pull all the data from the server THEN apply a filter, or to pass the variables to the server.  It would seem to me to be better to pull all the data into memory and then work with it.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. This is very likely going to be closed because there is nowhere near enough information here. You only sort of vaguely explain the problem. I would urge you to read what you posted and ask yourself if you could even understand the question, let alone provide any type of solution.

Comment: I am not looking for someone to "solve" my problem.  What I am looking for is guidance into where to find the solution.  I don't want or need you to write the code for me, I want to learn and be able to write it myself.  However, I will try to edit my post to add more detail if you can tell me what detail is needed.

Comment: "how to properly build a WHERE clause that would have 12 variables in it. " By joining them to gether with lots of ANDs and ORs, I guess. Without knowing the exact nature of the query it's hard to know what else to say. A where clause can have as many sections as you like. Didn't you write some equivalent SQL in your Access database? If you used the query builder you can see the SQL it generates and work from there. It would help a lot if we could see relevant parts of the code which is giving you trouble, and what you've got so far, then we can narrow down the issue.

Comment: This is far too broad for SO.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour] to learn how to get the most out of the site.  Researching the tools you are using on MSDN might be a good idea too, so you can compose a question that can be answered.

Comment: I have edited my question - I'm hoping this will be more detailed and able to be answered???

Comment: I would configure each combo box to have its own dataset retrieving just the distinct rows for that combobox.  The dataset for the gridview would be repopulated every time a combo box changes.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a single results gridview to be filtered by the optional selection of 8 different combo boxes.

When you generate the query for the gridview, you'll need to selectively include the where clauses for each combo box with a value.  That should be as simple as `sql += " AND Combobox2Column = @Combobox2Value "` for each combo box.  Don't bother using the column like '%' pattern for combo boxes with no selection.  That can have negative performance impacts and is not necessary if you build your query in VB before sending to the database.
(This is a scenario when using "WHERE 1=1" as the first predicate in the where clause comes in handy.  It does have a little bit of overhead, but it standardizes all the rest of the predicates to always start with AND to prevent the additional overhead of determining if the specific combo box is the only combo box with a value selected.  If your query requires any other filters not based on the combo box, this becomes unnecessary)

Another important factor is that changing any combo box will trigger the event to refresh the contents of the grid view.  Put your combo box refresh logic in a dedicated method, separate from an event handler.  Then you can easily call that method from the event handler for each combo box (or any other control/event).

Hope that helps.

Comment: I think this gets me a little closer.  I never thought to use a LISTBOX as I was stuck on DataGridView as that is what all the other examples used.  I also really like your idea for the WHERE 1=1 and then adding all the AND statements.  That will make the code look a lot cleaner.  I will go in this direction and see if I can solve my issues.  If not, I'll come back and try to post a better question.

Comment: @Cory Sorry, I was using Access control vernacular for the listbox.  I would use an asp:GridView to display the data.  I updated my answer to call them it a grid view rather than a list box.

Comment: OK... I'm still willing to try that.  How do I get the results to be a query pointing to an existing dataset?